# Convert all existing tabs to spaces in VS Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint

Got a React app which has tabs in all the files, and I want to implement *eslint* change to 2 spaces.

Is there a way to convert all existing tabs to spaces in VS Code all at once?

Answer (score 2):

Do a "regular expression" find and replace all (`CTRL + SHIFT + H`, then enable the `.*` option or press `ALT + R`), and replace `\t` (tab), with   (1 or more spaces).

Comment: `Ctrl + H` will not work across multiple files. `Ctrl + Shift + H` will open the multi-file replace pane.

Answer (score 1):

One option to do this is to use Find and Replace across multiple files.
The shortcut to the Replace pane is `Ctrl+Shift+H`, then you can search for a tab and replace it with two spaces.

This is distinct from regular `Ctrl+F` or `Ctrl+H` as it can operate across the entire project, rather than each individual file.

Be cautious of this if there is the possibility of tabs being used for something other than indentation.

To find out more about the Find/Replace tools in VS Code, see:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-across-files
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-and-replace